# Action of continuous function on boundary.

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $T_r=\{x\in R^n:||x||<r\}$,$f:\overline T_r \rightarrow R^n$ is continuous

condition 1: $\forall \lambda >0,x\in\partial T_r$  , $f(-x)\ne\lambda f(x)$

condition 2: $\forall \lambda >0,x\in\partial T_r$  , $f(-x)\ne -\lambda f(x)$

How do I prove $f$ must meet only one of condition 1 or condition 2?

Comment: This guess is not complete right. There are functions don't meet 1 and 2. But meeting only one is right. If I am free ,I will give a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guess is not right, it should be corrected $f$ can't meet 1 and 2, I mean the condition 1 and condition 2 can't be meet by a  continuous function $f$.

Let $K$ is the $n-1$ dim plane , and $\theta\in K$. Then, let $\pi :R^n\rightarrow K$ is a project.So, $\pi\circ f: T_r\rightarrow K$ is continuous.By Borsuk Ulam theorem, $\exists x\in \partial T_r$ st $\pi\circ f(x)=\pi\circ f(-x)$. So the $f(x) $ and $f(-x)$ in same line .

So, condition 1 and condition 2 can be meet all.